# android - http post content-length (json post)

Tags: android, json, post

I need to create a post request for user login. I am setting Content-Length header but when i post request it gives **org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Length Required**

My code

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("UserName", username);
        data.put("Password", password);
        data.put("RememberMe", false);

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_PATH);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data.toString());
        httpost.setEntity(se);

        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-Length",""+se.getContentLength());

        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        return httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
```

When i set Content-Length header it gives 'Content-Length header already present' , and when remove content-lenght header it gives 'Length is required'

Thanks.

Comment: Solved with HttpURLConnection inntead of DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 httpost.setHeader("Content-Lenght",""+se.getContentLength());
```

to

```
 httpost.setHeader("Content-Length",""+se.getContentLength());
```

because currently you are passing `Content-Lenght` (Length spelling mistake) instead of `Content-Length`  as key to `setHeader` method

Comment: Sorry for it. I missed it. When i set Content-Length header it gives 'Content-Length header already present' , and when remove content-lenght header it gives 'Length is required'

Comment: @dracula, were you able to solve the  'Content-Length header already present' problem? I am hitting the same. Help me here.

Comment: @Gopinath , yes i've solved with HttpURLConnection and setting RequestProperties of connection